# Get a Java string of form (num/num), to become two double values

Tags: java, string, double

For example, if I have a string (24/25), how would I go about being left with two double values of 24 and 25. My objective to to eventually, given a set of number of that form, divide each of them, and add to get the average. I'm fairly new to Java and I honestly am so confused as where to even begin. Thank you!

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here... [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)). Javadoc's are a powerful thing ;)

Comment: I would say -  *start with a decent java tutorial* :)

Comment: Look at javadoc of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html), and you should be able to figure it out. Methods to use are `indexOf()`, `substring()`, and `parseDouble()`.

Answer (score 1):

As Andreas said. First you need to take the substring between brackets. Use [`String.substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

Now split 24/25 to 24 and 25. You can use [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Then you can parse them with [`Double.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

Comment: Input is `(24/25)`, not `24/25`.

Comment: Also, given how green OP seems to be, I'd steer towards `indexOf()` and `substring()`, rather than a method like `split()` which uses a *regular expression* and *arrays*.

Comment: There are many methods to do that. This is a possibility. Also building a parser is a possibility, one code is enough to start.